# SpriteKit addChild(node: SKNode) plural?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

Is there a plural version of this command, so I can type in a list of children to add?

Kind of like:

```
addChildren(myNodeABC, myNodeXYZ, myNode123)
```

Comment: no, you will have to make your own

Comment: Argh, wonderful, @Knight0fDragon. I shall try to use what i've gleaned of extensions and post here for you to chuckle at when done...

Comment: But don't hold your breath, I have a few other things to do, it could be a few days, or weeks before I get around to it. And that's just coding time ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Write an extension to do it: (I wrote it in Swift 3 style<s>, I do not have XCode available right now to verify this works</s>)

```
extension SKNode
{
    func add(children: SKNode...)  {
        for child in children{
            addChild(child)
        }
    }
}
```

usage:

```
node.add(children:node1,node2,node3)
```

note:
   `...` is called variadic parameters in case you want to know more about them: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html

If you want to use less lines, do:

```
extension SKNode
{
    func add(children: SKNode...)  {
        children.forEach({addChild($0)});
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow. variadic is VERY cool. Like an instant array, without having to create one.

Comment: Yes, that have existed since the days of C, since command line apps needed a way to accept a variable amount of parameters

Comment: You are a LEGEND! At your best, you are one of the best!

Comment: Which is a cheeky reminder that you sometimes make comments and respond needlessly aggressively within the rules of SO, but not necessarily within the 'rules' of consideration, caring, empathy and love. But I recognise that the SO rules make no allowances for these esoteric values of the heart and soul.